# EVM compatible chains and Substrate Bridges

Tags: evm, bridge

I am looking for a bridging solution between EVM compatible chains and a substrate-based solo chain (i.e. not a parachain).
The bridges is purely for cross chain asset transfer.
I am aware of the [parity bridges common](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/find/master) framework. However I was looking for a more high level solution, such as [`Darwinia`](https://darwinia.network/), however it doesn’t support Polygon yet (for example)
What solutions do you recommend?